# Use new version of mingw-g++

Tags: 12.04, g++, mingw32

My machine currently runs on Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit version). I tried installing mingw-g++ for it, however, it installs an older version of g++, from the 4.6 series.

Is there anyway I could download one of the later versions namely [this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++-mingw-w64-x86-64)?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Because you are running 12.04 and not 14.04, where 14 is trusty and 12 is precise.  Since there is two different OS versions, you would need Trusty to get the one you want.  To be precise, 12 and 14 use two different Repos, both labeled Universe.

I would not recommend installing newer software not designed for older OS versions.